# How to create dynamic operation with between at filter statement in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to add filter with operation and between statement

table have a birthday column, so I have to use it.

first I try to this sql

```
select birthdate from user_table
where ROUND((CURRENT_DATE - birthdate) / 365) between 10 and 30
```

seems find in database but I don't know how to write in sqlalchemy

I tried this code

```
user_tag = session.query(
    (datetime.datetime.now() - UserTags.birthdate) / 365
).all()
```

I got result sucessfully but when I try to with filter, I lost my way

```
user_tag = session.query(
    User.birthdate
).filter(
    ???? // I want to use it with between statement.
).all()
```

How can I make sqlachemy code corresponds to

```
select birthdate from user_table
where ROUND((CURRENT_DATE - birthdate) / 365) between 10 and 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form the function expression and apply [`between()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.between):

```
user_tag = session.query(
    func.round((func.current_date() - UserTags.birthdate) / 365).between(10, 30)
).all()
```